# $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ limits involving $\sin x$

Tags: calculus, epsilon-delta

Currently I'm studying limits by definition and I've seen lots of cases where at some point of the proof, for some given function that involves something of the form:

$\sin [f(x_1 \dots x_n)]$ where $f$ is some scalar field

People use the fact that

$\sin [f(x_1 \dots x_n)] \leq f(x_1 \dots x_n)$

Instead of using:

$\sin [f(x_1 \dots x_n)] \leq 1$

Is it bad to always use the latter? Am I loosing some generality or something?

Comment: Perhaps some of the proofs you are using require the ``small angle formula." See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-angle_approximation).

Comment: @JWP_HTX Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mean-value theorem gives us the estimate $|\sin x|\leq |x|$ for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$. We also have $|\sin x|\leq 1$ for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$, and therefore, we have for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$,
\begin{align}
|\sin x|\leq \min(1,|x|).
\end{align}
Now, sometimes, all we care about is that $\sin$ is a bounded function, in which case we just use the upper bound $1$. On the other hand, sometimes, we may be analyzing a function $f$ which is quite small, i.e $|f|\leq 1$ and in this case if we require more precise estimates on $\sin \circ f$, then we use the second type of estimate. It is all a matter of context.

As an example of a situation where the crude and obvious bound of $1$ is insufficient, consider the following problem:

> Prove that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x}=0$.

If you use the crude estimate $|\sin (x^2)|\leq 1$, then you only obtain $\left|\frac{\sin (x^2)}{x}\right|\leq \frac{1}{|x|}$, and this is a useless bound because $\frac{1}{|x|}\to \infty$ as $x\to 0$.

On the other hand, if you use the stronger estimate, then $\left|\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x}\right|\leq \left|\frac{x^2}{x}\right|=|x|$, and now the RHS approaches $0$ as $x\to 0$. SO, in this manner, we are able to prove the limit.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was clarifying. So I can assume that this reasoning applies to every narrowing we apply.